# Can I add an additional error class for my div tags?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a large form built with [twitter's bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#forms) kit.  The fields look like so:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <label for="state_id">State</label>
    <div class="input">
        <select id="state_id" name="state">
           <option value="122">Alabama</option><option value="123">Alaska</option><option value="124">Arizona</option> 
        </select>
    </div>
</div><!-- /clearfix -->
<div class="clearfix">
    <label for="city_id">City</label>
    <div class="input">
        <input type="text" id="city_id" name="city" value="" />
    </div>
</div><!-- /clearfix -->
```

They offer an error class that highlights the field in red like so:

```
<div class="clearfix error">
    <label for="state_id">State</label>
    <div class="input">
        <select id="state_id" name="state">
             <option value="122">Alabama</option><option value="123">Alaska</option><option value="124">Arizona</option> 
        </select>
    </div>
</div><!-- /clearfix -->
```

Is there a way to use jquery and validate my form fields and add this class if needed?

My jquery call is simply:

```
$('#form_submit').click(function(){

    var formValid = true;

    $("div.clearfix").each(function() {
            // 
    });
});
```

Comment: jQuery, and JavaScript work client-side, not the server. Could you post the generated HTML that your browser sees (view source), rather than the server-side PHP script?

Comment: I would like to validate it client side. I basically just need to validate that a value has been entered and the fields are not empty.

Comment: Yes. May I repeat my request: ***Could you post the generated HTML that your browser sees (view source), rather than the server-side PHP script?***

Comment: And your JavaScript/jQuery? (Sorry, I'm not *trying* to be picky, but I forgot to ask the first two times...sigh... =/ ).

Comment: no worries, nothing yet for jquery just the click event

Comment: You might want to try [jQuery Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Comment: With jQuery Validate you can tell it where to place the 'error' class (or you can declare another treatment/class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can consider use the jquery validation [plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) just to make the validation rules. Really is a powerful plugin.

example:

```
$("input [type='text']").rules("add", { minlength: 2 });
```

So, when you calls `$("form").validate()` this function returns all invalid fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your forms with above plugin or any other way and then if you find the validation error then use

```
 $("#city_id_input_div").addClass("error");
```

Where you have to give the id to the each div to which you need to apply the 'error' class.

For example

```
<div class="clearfix" is="city_id_input_div">
<label for="city_id">City</label>
<div class="input">
    <input type="text" id="city_id" name="city" value="" class="large" onclick="removeErrorClass('city_id_input_div');" onkeypress="removeErrorClass('city_id_input_div');"/>
</div>
```

```
  function removeErrorClass(id)
  {  
    $("#"+id).removeClass("error"); 
  }
```

this is my way to use 'error' class of the Bootstrap dynamically and remove that class dynamically.